# How to avoid code duplication in java when working with two implementations of an abstract class

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have two java classes that do the same thing but their output depends on the value of two attributes that are of the same type, but each class has different values for the attributes. Also each class input and output type are different but they implement the same abstract class. How can I avoid duplicated code?

```
public class ClassA {
    private MyClass1 attr1;
    private myClass2 attr2;
    
    public ResponseA doSomething(RequestA request) {
        // do something with attr1 and attr2 and request
        return ResponseA.builder().build();
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    private myClass1 attr1;
    private myClass2 attr2;
    
    public ResponseB doSomething(RequestB request) {
        // do something with attr1 and attr2 and request
        return ResponseB.builder().build();
    }
}

public abstract class RequestType {
     
}

public class RequestA extends RequestType {

}

public class RequestB extends RequestType {

}

public abstract class ResponseType {
    // can't have a builder
}

public class ResponseA extends ResponseType {
    // has a builder
}

public class ResponseB extends ResponseType {
    // has a builder
}
```

How can I make it so that I don't have to repeat the implementation of `doSomething` twice (or more than twice in the future.

I tried with an interface, but had problems because I need to access the value of the attributes inside `doSomething` so I couldn't just put the implementation of the method in the interface.

The problem I have for abstract class is that, since `ResponseType` doesn't have a builder (neither can I touch that class), I can't build the object from the abstract class, because I need to know which subclass I'm working with to call that builder.

Comment: Create another abstract class that extends the original, and put all the common code/variables in there.